# Cannot get Vipps in payment window

Tags: php, bambora

Using the code sample from [here](https://developer.bambora.com/europe/checkout/getting-started/create-payment), I wish to add payment with Vipps to the payment options, so I added the following key-values [as per the documentation](https://developer.bambora.com/europe/checkout/getting-started/checkout-settings) to the request:

```
$request['paymentwindow'] = [
  'paymentmethods' => [
    [
      'id' => 'paymentcard',
      'action' => 'include'
    ],
    [
      'id' => 'vipps',
      'action' => 'include'
    ]
  ]
];
```

But, this seems to have no effect and no option for payment with Vipps is added to the payment window. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: Vipps is only available in production account